# pip not finding an installed python package

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install the statsmodels, but I'm getting a dependency error that statsmodels requires patsy. However patsy is already installed:

```
Baby-Whip$ sudo pip install patsy
Downloading/unpacking patsy
Downloading patsy-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (224kB): 224kB downloaded
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from patsy)
Installing collected packages: patsy
Successfully installed patsy
Cleaning up...
```

Then when I try to install stasmodels:

```
Baby-Whip$ sudo pip install statsmodels
Downloading/unpacking statsmodels
Downloading statsmodels-0.5.0.tar.gz (5.5MB): 5.5MB downloaded
Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py) egg_info for package statsmodels
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py", line 463, in <module>
    check_dependency_versions(min_versions)
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py", line 122, in check_dependency_versions
    raise ImportError("statsmodels requires patsy. http://patsy.readthedocs.org")
ImportError: statsmodels requires patsy. http://patsy.readthedocs.org
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py", line 463, in <module>

check_dependency_versions(min_versions)

File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py", line 122, in check_dependency_versions

raise ImportError("statsmodels requires patsy. http://patsy.readthedocs.org")

ImportError: statsmodels requires patsy. http://patsy.readthedocs.org
```

Running pip freeze also lists patsy as an installed package. What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://patsy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html#installation read the following page, follow all requirements then try again

Comment: Ah! I was missing Six - patsy can apparently install without it, but packages that depend on patsy cannot. Also, this workaround was critical: http://bruteforce.gr/bypassing-clang-error-unknown-argument.html

Comment: there you go my good sir.

Answer (score 1):

See above comment for answer. Needed to install six, and run the statmodels install with the above workaround.

Sidenote: kill me